# AWS CDK MSK get bootstrap server list for an existing cluster

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-msk, aws-cdk-typescript

I am trying to deploy AWS Fargate services, written in Spring boot to consume messages from an existing MSK Kafka cluster using AWS CDK.   I can get the `ICluster` reference using the method `const kafkaCluster = msk.Cluster.fromClusterArn(...)`. But how do i get the bootstrap server URL for the application to use.

msk.Cluster class has a field "bootstrapBrokers"  as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-msk-alpha-readme.html#cluster-endpoints).but how can I get the bootstrap brokers list from the cluster information got via `msk.Cluster.fromClusterArn(...)` ?